# Hackerrank Sock Merchant Challenge - STDIN and STDOUT with R

Tags: r, function, stdout, stdin

I have spent a fair deal of time trying to have a go at this but to little success. I am basically trying to work out the sock merchant challenge from Hackerrank on R. **The challenge itself is quite straight forward, but I am really struggling to come to terms with STDIN and STDOUT.** Most help available pertains to Python, so I would be really grateful for any help.

Following is the description of the challenge:

> John works at a clothing store. He has a large pile of socks that he must pair by color for sale. Given an array of integers representing the color of each sock, determine how many pairs of socks with matching colors there are.  For example, there are ***n=7*** socks with colors ***ar = [1,2,1,2,1,3,2]*** . There is one pair of color **1** and one of color **2**. There are three odd socks left, one of each color. The number of pairs is **2**.

> **Function Description**: Complete the sockMerchant function in the editor below. It must return an integer representing the number of matching pairs of socks that are available. sockMerchant has the following parameter(s):

- n: the number of socks in the pile
- ar: the colors of each sock

> **Input Format**:
> The first line contains an integer, the number of socks represented in.
> The second line contains space-separated integers describing the colors of the socks in the pile.

> **Output Format**: Return the total number of matching pairs of socks that John can sell.

Here is my simple attempt, and it works just fine on RStudio

```
sockmerchant <- function(n,ar){
  unique.values <- unique(ar)
  count <- rep(0, length(unique.values))
  for (i in 1:length(unique.values)){
    count[i] <- sum(ar == unique.values[i])
  }
  temp <- count/2
  pairs <- floor(temp)
  return(sum(pairs))
}
```

However, I am not sure how to make this code stdin/stdout compliant as Hackerrank requires. My main challenge is how to make this function interpretable on Hackerrank. How should I modify the code so that it reads input from STDIN and prints the output to STDOUT.

Comment: `readLines` will return a character vector. `as.numeric` will convert that to a numeric vector (and turn any non-numeric values to NA).

Answer (score 0):

Each input to `readLines` is interpreted as text, so you need to convert to numeric values for the calculation. The second line would need to be split by spaces to return a vector of integers which would then be converted to numbers.

```r
sockmerchant <- function() {
  cat("Enter total number of socks: ")
  n <- as.numeric(readLines(n = 1))
  cat("\nEnter colors of socks as integers separated by spaces: ")
  ar  <- as.numeric(strsplit(readLines(n = 1), " +")[[1]])
  if (length(ar) != n) stop("The number of socks doesn't match the color list!")
  unique.values <- unique(ar)
  count <- rep(0, length(unique.values))
  for (i in 1:length(unique.values)){
    count[i] <- sum(ar == unique.values[i])
  }
  temp <- count/2
  pairs <- floor(temp)
  return(sum(pairs))
}
```

It would work like this:

```
> sockmerchant()
Enter total number of socks: 
7

Enter colors of socks as integers separated by spaces: 
3 5 7 3 5 7 9
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, my challenge is how to read input from STDIN and print output to STDOUT for the above function. I hope I make myself more clear now.

Comment: @ObaidRehman this _does_ read from STDIN. It reads from `readLines` which by default reads from STDIN. If you want to output to STDOUT you can `cat` or `print` the result instead of `return` ing it. The example I showed of using the function was of inputting the numbers via STDIN

Comment: Thanks once again! I must be misunderstanding something here as I am fairly new to Hackerrank platform. I basically copied your suggested code as it is on the hackerrank editor, and I obtain the following messages when it processes the code on test data.                                                                           
                                                                                                                               Error (stderr)
Error in strsplit(readLines(n = 1), " +")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: sockmerchant
Execution halted